# Executing a bat file on a different machine and getting the output

Tags: java, batch-file

I need to execute a `.cmd` file which is on a different machine. I can access the file system of that machine like: `\\IP\Location\File.cmd`

The code I have is from : http://omtlab.com/java-how-to-run-exe-file-and-batch-file-using-java-program/

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GetResponseMain {
    //This is Example that display how to get response using java
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String filePath = "\\\\255.255.255.0\\Scripts\\ClearCache.cmd";
        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);
            p.waitFor();
            InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int c = -1;
            while((c = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                baos.write(c);
            }

            String response = new String(baos.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Response: "+response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This code was supposed to print the output. But it shows the contents of the `.cmd` file.

I think that instead of executing the script on that machine. It is executing it locally. 
So how can I fix that?

Comment: Well in the batch file world we usually use Microsoft's PSEXEC utility to execute code on a remote computer.

Comment: @Squashman can you please explain a little?

Comment: I know nothing about java so I would not be able to explain how to make it work in java.  I just know that if I need to execute a batch file on a remote computer I use psexec. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx

Comment: Even if the command is being executed locally (which is unlikely), why would that cause the command to print its own contents?

Comment: @VGR because `@echo off` was left out from the top of the batch file.

Comment: Your java code has no awareness of where the file is located. As far as it is concerned it is just a "file" on your file system. It runs it (as if you run it locally on command line). Isn't that what you expect from it? But, why does it show the commands as it executes? May be because you are echoing them?

Comment: You need to use WMI or Windows Script Host. The command line WMIC.exe mirrors the COM objects. So `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "\\127.0.0.1\C$\windows\notepad.exe"`. Help for command line or programming `wmic /?`, `wmic process get /?`, `wmic process call /?`, `wmic /node /?`.

Comment: @blackpen The `cmd` file is not written by me. But when I run that file on the remote machine itself, it executes correctly. But when I try running it on my system. It doesen't. Do you want me to post the contents of the `cmd` file?

Comment: @VGR The cmd file is not written by me. But when I run that file on the remote machine itself, it executes correctly. But when I try running it on my system. It doesen't. Do you want me to post the contents of the cmd file?

Comment: @Nivedita, Sure, that would help. Also you could post the errors.

Comment: @blackpen I am not getting any errors. And I cannot post the complete script as it is not written by me. If you need to know any specific details, please tell me. I will check if its their in the file or not.

Comment: When you say, "It doesn't execute correctly on my system", do you mean when you run it through java as you shown above OR do you mean when you run the script directly on the command line like _**C:>myscript.bat**_ ? And how do you know that it didn't execute correctly? Is there any indication?

Comment: @blackpen Both. And I know it didn't execute correctly, because it shows different output on the machine on which it is actually located.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first concern is: Can the *`File.cmd`* be run on local machine? Because of lack of suitable software on local machine (that the *`File.cmd`* depends on), it may fail to run. If it gives errors when you run it on command line, it will also give the same errors when you run it through java. Making it suitable to be run on local machine may be a long task, depending on how complicated the *`File.cmd`* is, and what software needs to be installed on your local machine to make it work.

On the other hand, if you want to run it on remote machine itself (while you are sitting at the terminal of local machine), you can use ***`PsExec`*** or ***`wmic`*** as pointed out by others in comments.